# How to properly install azure-cli in Ubuntu 20.04 using homebrew?

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, homebrew, azure-cli

I am trying to install the `azure-cli` locally from a cloned repository. I successfully installed homebrew on my end. However, when I try to install the `azure-cli`, the error occurs below at the very end:

[image]

From the repository, the instructions work on other devices, both on windows and linux. I don't know why it won't work on my end:
Step 1: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` 
Step 2: `brew tap-new <name>/azure-cli` 
Step 3: `brew extract azure-cli <name>/azure-cli --version 2.29.2` 
Step 4: `brew install <name>/azure-cli/azure-cli@2.29.2` (This is where error occurs)

*Note: the  section is the name of the user of my laptop.

Other part of the installation process I've successfully installed:
Decorator setup: 
`sudo apt install python3-pip`
`sudo /usr/bin/pip3 install --system decorator`
Azure Functions Core Tools:
`npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have ran the below cmdlets in our local environment to install Home brew & azure cli on azure Linux virtual machine which is running with Ubuntu 20.04 image.

**Here are the list of Linux cmdlets used:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt install git -y ##installing git 
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" ##Run Homebrew installation Script
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)" ##Add Homebrew to your path
```

To ensure everything is working correctly to use brew, we can run its command

```
  brew doctor
```

It may give the warning to install GCC and to remove that simply install it using brew

```
 brew install gcc
```

To install azure-cli with last version as per the [documentation](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/azure-cli)

```
brew install azure-cli
```

Here is the output screenshot for reference:

[image]

[image]

You can refer this [blog](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/azure-cli) to install home brew on Ubuntu20.04 linux machine.